# Covert a String to an Object which has a variable name

Tags: arrays, .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I searched for two hours, here on Stackoverflow and on other forums. But i can't find a solution for my problem. I have to be able to change the properties of an object that has a name that I don't know. Now i try to explain better:
The user drag some files in a form, and i get in a array() all the paths of the dragged files. For each path in files() i add to a panel a usercontrol that is the interface of an uploader. (My application it's kind of an uploader). Good, imagine that the user dragged 4 files, i have 4 different usercontrols, named "Uploader1", "Uploader2", "Uploader3" and "Uploader4". I need to change the text of a label in the uploader1, but i can't write:

```
 Uploader1.LabelExample.Text = "Example"
```

Becouse it doesn't exist! (Not yet!)
So i tryed this method.

```
Dim UploadCounter as Integer = 1
Dim CurrentUploader = CType(Panel.Controls("Uploader" & UploaderCounter.ToString), UploadBanner)
CurrentUploader.LabelExample.Text = "Example"
```

I write the same with DirectCast and TryCast, but nothing.
I try also:

```
For Each Uploader With{.Name = "Uploader1"} as UploaderControl in Panel.Controls
   Uploader.LabelExample.Text = "Example"
Next
```

I searched everywhere for "convert string to an object in vb.net"  but i can't find anything that work! They all return "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Sorry for my bad bad english, thanks for all that will help me! need really!

Comment: You can simply add your UserControls to a `List(Of TheirType)`. Or use a class object that keeps track of the UCs instances you create/destroy and which exposes methods/properties to handle them. In any case, don't just blindly add Controls to a Parent container without any means to access them after, since you apparently need to. You could also build a *self-aware* UC, which exposes all the methods/properties and events needed for the task, so once initialized, they're *ready-to-go*, just using their Controls.

Comment: *For each path in files() i add to a panel* - show the code that does this